# There is an error in XML document (1, 41)

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

When i am doing Deserialize of xml i am getting "There is an error in XML document (1, 41)." . Can anyone tell me about what is the issue is all about.

```
 public static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string xml)
        {
            T result;
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (TextReader tr = new StringReader(xml))
            {
                result = (T)ser.Deserialize(tr);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

I use this function to do it.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-16'?>
<Message>
<FirstName>Hunt</FirstName>
<LastName>DAvid</LastName>
</Message>
```

Comment: You might want to include (a part of) that XML document, especially line 1 position 41.

Comment: It will help if you could copy the whole error message and put it as part of your question.

Comment: And also which tool you use to deserialise the xml.

Comment: Have you specified `XmlRoot("Message")] ` for the class of `T` you are using when deserializing???

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ensure your Message class looks like below:

```
[Serializable, XmlRoot("Message")]
public class Message
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

This works for me fine:

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText("c:\\Message.xml");
var result = DeserializeFromXml<Message>(xml);
```

[MSDN, XmlRoot.ElementName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.elementname%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> The name of the XML root element that is generated and recognized in
>   an XML-document instance. **The default is the name of the serialized
>   class**.

So it might be your class name is not `Message` and this is why deserializer was not able find it using default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you! I've realized that I must always set the property `ElementName` within `XmlRoot` attribute, because it's not known ahead of time whether the the class' name will be changed in the process of refactoring.

Answer (score 5):

First check the variables declared using proper Datatypes.
I had a same problem then I have checked, by mistake I declared SAPUser as int datatype so that the error occurred.
One more thing XML file stores its data using concept like array but its first index starts having +1.
e.g. if error is in(7,2) then
check for 6th line always.....

Answer (score 4):

Agreed with the answer from sll, but experienced another hurdle which was having specified a namespace in the attributes, when receiving the return xml that namespace wasn't included and thus failed finding the class.

i had to find a workaround to specifying the namespace in the attribute and it worked.

ie.

```
[Serializable()]
    [XmlRoot("Patient", Namespace = "http://www.xxxx.org/TargetNamespace")]
    public class Patient
```

generated

```
<Patient xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.xxxx.org/TargetNamespace">
```

but I had to change it to

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("Patient")]
public class Patient
```

which generated to

```
<Patient xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

This solved my problem, hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thing. All came down to a "d" instead of a "D" in a tag name in the schema.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a float value expected where xml had a null value so be sure to search for float and int data type in your xsd map

Answer (score 0):

On a WEC7 project I'm working on, I got a similar error. The file I was serializing in was serialized out from an array of objects, so I figured the XML was fine. Also, I have had this working for a few previous classes, so it was quite a puzzle.

Then I noticed in my earlier work that every class that I was serializing/deserializing had a default constructor. That was missing in my failed case so I added it and and voila... it worked fine.

I seem to remember reading somewhere that this was required. I guess it is.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to de-serialize decimal into float, which was throwing the excpetion . Always try to look into inner exception as this is generic excpetion . Inner exception will give you the exact cause of issue . Happy Coding .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).